# How do you change the date format of Indonesia in Carbon Laravel?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I want to change the date format to the Indonesian date format.
I have added code like this in app/Providers/AppSserviceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{

    config(['app.locale' => 'id']);
    \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('id');
}
```

and I call him a command like this:

```
 \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('id');
 echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('l, d F Y');
```

but it did not work well, the date format was not yet Indonesian. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control timezone of your application in the `timezone` variable inside `config/app.php` file.
Don't foget to clear cache after: `php artisan config:cache`.

upd: try this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND');
echo \Carbon\Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that. I'd keep the timestamp in UTC and convert it per request to the desired time format/timezone. This will make time converting and management easier if you have users from different parts of the world. This will obviously presume that each user has their preferred timezone defined.

Answer (score 0):

Silakan dicoba kawan :

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2021-03-16 08:27:00')->locale('id');

$date->settings(['formatFunction' => 'translatedFormat']);

echo $date->format('l, j F Y ; h:i a'); // Selasa, 16 Maret 2021 ; 08:27 pagi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control timezone of your application in the timezone variable inside `config/app.php` file. Don't foget to clear cache after: `php artisan config:clear`.

and try this in app.php:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Jakarta'
```

then your carbon like this:

```
Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A, %d %B %Y')
```